# Temperature dependence of superconducting gap near critical temperature

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity

I am trying to understand the calculation in the book *Methods of Quantum field theory in statistical physics* by A.A. Abrikosov, L.P Grokov & I.E. Dzyaloshinski on page 304 about the temperature dependence of the superconducting gap near the critical temperature. The Ansatz is the following. We starting with the equation

$$
\frac{1}{g\rho} = T\sum_{n}\int_{-\omega_{d}}^{\omega_{d}}\frac{d\epsilon}{\Omega_{n}^{2} + \epsilon^{2} + \Delta^{2}}
$$

Further, we know that near $T_{C}$ that the superconducting gap is very small so that we can make a Taylor Expansion

$$
T\sum_{n}\int_{-\omega_{d}}^{\omega_{d}}\frac{d\epsilon}{\Omega_{n}^{2} + \epsilon^{2} + \Delta^{2}} = T\sum_{n}\int_{-\omega_{d}}^{\omega_{d}}d\epsilon\left[\frac{1}{\Omega_{n}^{2} + \epsilon^{2}}-\frac{\Delta^{2}}{\left(\Omega_{n}^{2} + \epsilon^{2}\right)^{2}}+\frac{\Delta^{4}}{\left(\Omega_{n}^{2} + \epsilon^{2}\right)^{3}}\right]
$$

Then, the next step in the book is for me not direct clear:

$$
T\sum_{n}\int_{-\omega_{d}}^{\omega_{d}}d\epsilon\left[\frac{1}{\Omega_{n}^{2} + \epsilon^{2}}-\frac{\Delta^{2}}{\left(\Omega_{n}^{2} + \epsilon^{2}\right)^{2}}+\frac{\Delta^{4}}{\left(\Omega_{n}^{2} + \epsilon^{2}\right)^{3}}\right] = \int_{0}^{\omega_{d}}d\epsilon\frac{\tanh\left(\frac{\epsilon}{2T}\right)}{\epsilon}-\frac{\Delta^{2}}{\left(\pi T\right)^{2}}\sum_{n}\frac{1}{\left(2n + 1\right)^{3}} + \frac{3\Delta^{4}}{4\left(\pi T\right)^{4}}\sum_{n}\frac{1}{\left(2n + 1\right)^{5}}
$$

I have no idea why this should be true. Why should be there $\frac{\Delta^{2}}{\left(\pi T\right)^{2}}$ and $\frac{3\Delta^{4}}{4\left(\pi T\right)^{4}}$ and have can I obtain $\sum_{n}\frac{1}{\left(2n + 1\right)^{3}}$ (and $\sum_{n}\frac{1}{\left(2n + 1\right)^{5}}$) from the Integration?

Comment: The sums are over the Matsubara frequencies, defined as $\omega_{n}=2\pi T (n+1/2)$ for fermions (in the book they are defined as $\omega_{n}$, not $\Omega_{n}$, at least not in my version ! The sums over Matsubara frequencies are tabulated. Check the chapter on the book about non-zero temperature Green's functions.

Comment: @FraSchelle: Thanks. I found the solution now by myself. I will write later the answer.